# Powershell websession

Tags: powershell

My question is, I'm logging into a website using invoke web-request.  I'm able to successfully login to the website.  My problem is that, when I go to a url, it thinks I'm not logged in.  I'm using the same session variable to login and to go to the specific page.

This is the screenshot showing I'm logged in, but I can't go the part of the website to upload some files.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=18tr4aBxTkroQKl1E1SOAEyeJ70LH2LC0

```
$Global:organization = Read-Host "`tEnter the organization"
$username = Read-Host "`tEnter the username"
$password = Read-Host "`tEnter the password"

$form.fields["organization"] = $organization
$form.fields["Username"] = $username
$form.fields["Password"] = $password

$Global:loginResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -uri ("https://dealer.md-bmc.rpdss.com/" + $form.Action) -WebSession $login -Method post -Body $form.Fields

if ($loginResponse.ParsedHtml.title -eq "RAPID Dealer Reporting Site") {
    Write-Host "`tLog in failed, please try again! `n" -ForegroundColor Red
}

else {
$info = $loginResponse.AllElements | where {$_.tagName -contains "span"}
$account = ($info.innerhtml | Select-Object -First 3).ToUpper()
Write-Host "`tLogged in as" $account "`n" -ForegroundColor Green
$upload = $loginResponse.AllElements.InnerHtml | Where-Object {$_ -match 'url="(administration/uploadprofileselector.aspx\?.*?)"'} |ForEach-Object {$matches[1]} | Select-Object -First 1

$uid = ($upload -replace '\D').Substring(0,4)
$oid = ($upload -replace '\D').Substring(4,6)

#this is where it "forgets" that it's already logged in.

$fileUploadurl = "https://dealer.md-bmc.rpdss.com/bwident/pawnshop/administration/uploadprofileselector.aspx?l=English&uid=$uid&oid=$oid"
$fileUploadPage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $fileUploadurl -WebSession $login

#this should be showing me a selection menu, but it's asking me to login again.  Please see screenshot.
$fileUploadPage.ParsedHtml.body.innerText
}
```

Comment: You are missing the "replace with" in `$upload -replace "\D"`

Comment: Thank you.  I'll correct it.  Still trying to figure out why it doesn't "remember" the login session.

Comment: I think you need `SessionVariable` in the first invoke-webrequest call. Not `WebSession`

Answer (score 2):

In the first call to `Invoke-WebRequest` you **set up** a session variable using the `-SessionVariable` parameter:

```
$Global:loginResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -uri ("https://dealer.md-bmc.rpdss.com/" + $form.Action) -SessionVariable login -Method post -Body $form.Fields
```

(as you can see, the variable name is without the `$` prefix here. You may even quote it like `'login'` to make it more clear it is just a name for a variable (string))

In subsequent calls to `Invoke-WebRequest` you **use** that session variable with the `-WebSession` parameter:

```
$fileUploadPage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $fileUploadurl -WebSession $login
```

p.s. as stated in my comment earlier, you will also have to fix the `($upload -replace '\D')` in your code because you are now trying to replace all characters that are not a digit with ????

Comment: I do have a session variable without the '$'.  I just forgot to past it before.  $Global:access = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $webSite -SessionVariable login

Comment: I fixed the -replaced '\D' to "\D"

Comment: No.. You need to replace the '\D' with SOMETHING. If you want to remove not- digits for instance, you do `-replace '\D', ''`

Comment: The -replace '\D' is doing exactly what I want it to do.  My main problem is that once I login, it's not taking me to the next page I want to go to even if I'm using the same session

Comment: Last try.. **Check your $login variable.** I suspect it is invalid, because you SHOULD get it from the line starting with `$Global:loginResponse`. That is where you authenticate for the site by sending your username and password. That is therefore the place to obtain the session variable using `-SessionVariable login`.

Comment: I did that, and still same result.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For me, Powershell Version 5 was always removing my Cookie if I added it any other way than this. What fixed my issue was:
Getting the cookie from the login request:

```
$webrequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $loginUrl -SessionVariable 'session' -Headers $headers -Method Post -Body $loginBody
$cookies = $session.Cookies.GetCookies($loginUrl)
```

Then manually construct a new Session with the cookie from the login, adding any required headers etc.

```
$url = [System.Uri]"https://someURl.com"
$Cookie_final = New-Object System.Net.Cookie($cookies[0].Name, $cookies[0].Value, '/')
$newSession = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$newSession.Cookies.Add($url, $Cookie_final)
$newSession.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*")
```

and finally sending the actual request with the constructed session:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Post -Body ($body | ConvertTo-Json) -WebSession $newSession
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late response, however:

PowerShell stores cookies using WebSession instance like a dictionary, where the key is a **full URL of the request** (sic!)

So, to use the cookies received on a previous call, you have to apply them to the new URL first:

```
    $login.Cookies.SetCookies("next-url-here", $login.Cookies.GetCookies("prev-url-here"))
```

Full workflow seems to be like this:

```
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "first-url-here" -SessionVariable login ...other-params-here...
    $login.Cookies.SetCookies("second-url-here", $login.Cookies.GetCookies("first-url-here")
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "second-url-here" -WebSession $login ...other-params-here...
```

Maybe, there is a special mode/param/etc that allows WebSession to zip all URLs into the single domain-level cookie storage, however I didn't find that one yet. (other than manually create it like @LeoniePinguin advised)